# Trying to build BND tool, getting gradle plugin error

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, bnd, bndtools

I'm trying to build the BND tool (v6.4) and running "gradle build" in the parent directory where the settings.gradle, build.gradle, etc are. I had to modify the settings.gradle to pull the depencency jar files from Artifactory and was able to resolve my dependency issues after that. However, now my build script runs for ~20 min before it complains that the plugin com.gradle.enterprise 3.11.1 was not found in any of the following sources:

Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)

I looked online for the com.gradle.enterprise plugin but I can't find any plugin by that name there. I only see "com.gradle.enterprise.gradle.plugin" v3.0 at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gradle.enterprise/com.gradle.enterprise.gradle.plugin/3.10. I tried changing my settings.gradle to use "id "com.gradle.enterprise.gradle.plugin" version "3.11.1"" but it can't find that either with the same error. Can anyone help me fix this? I'll also need to download the plugin that will be used so I can upload it to Artifactory so my settings.gradle can fetch it from there since my build isn't allowed to get dependencies from the web/non secure places besides my Artifactory server.

Here is part of the modified gradle settings

```
pluginManagement {
    plugins {
        id "com.gradle.enterprise" version "3.11.1"
    }
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    //mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven{
    url "<my/artifactory/url>"
    }
   }
  }
```